# MFC Spin/Edit Control

Tags: mfc

I am using an Spin Control with an Edit Control buddy. I have an OnEnChanged event as below

```
void MyClass::OnEnChangeSnrEdit()
{
  UpdateData(TRUE);
  wizard_data->wlan.min_snr = m_snr_spin.GetPos();
  CheckValid();
}
```

CheckValid enables the next button on my dialog page if the value is within the range I want it to be. The problem I have is that if I manually delete the value from the Edit Control so it is blank then GetPos above returns 0. 0 is within the range I allow and so my Next button is enabled and the value 0 is set when there is actually no value in the Edit Control.

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Simply check the Contents of the edit Control first. Only if it is not empty, then get the spin button Control.

But why to relay on the value of the spin Control. always use the value from the edit Control!